# Multiple variables sent with jquery ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

It's a silly question, but how can i pass multiple variables through ajax into php?
I tried this but doesn't quite suits my needs:

```
function modifica(estado){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "html",
    url: 'icallverifica.php',
    data: "verifica=1$other=4&gethis="+alerta,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
    });
}
```

EDIT:

Probably it's this:

```
data: {
    verifica : "xxx",
    numero : "yyy"
}
```

But i'll wait for the gurus to help

Comment: perhaps because you're using a `$` instead of an `&` in your querystring?

Comment: The second code snipet is the most flexible way of doing it. Why, are you having trouble with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after the page add a question mark(?) and then name=value pairs followed by ampersand(&) after each value

```
function modifica(estado){
    var action1 = "some text";
    var action2 = 2; // <-- numeric value
    var action3 = "some other text";
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "html",
    url: 'icallverifica.php?action1=' + escape( action1 ) + '&action2=' + escape( action2 ) + '&action3=' + escape(action3),
    data: "verifica=1$other=4&gethis="+alerta,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Although i didn't went this way, for caring about security, i will select as the best answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

For a get request you can append params to your url `'icallverifica.php?verifica=1&other=4&gethis='+alerta`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:`url: "data1="+ dataVar1 +"&data2="+ dataVar2` ... etc